# GIT clone repository not working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, git-clone

I am trying to clone a repository of my source code from Git URL to my local machine using VS 2022, but I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to start process. 
Process creation failed because the file cannot be found.
```

[image: GIT Clone error screenshot]

I googled and tried some of the solutions like "Uninstall and Reinstall GIT", but I get some issues while installing GIT also.
I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio, but still facing issue.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get some issues while installing GIT also

You will need to be more explicit on those issues, but that is the first step:

- install [Git for windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (the latest 2.40)
- make sure you can, from command-line, clone your repository.

[Visual Studio 2022 17.5 (March 2023)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1752--visual-studio-2022-version-1752) itself should include its own Git for Windows v2.39.2.